# Flutter - How to change style of the Textfield pop menu?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, textfield

[image]

When I hold the Textfield on long press, an edit toolbar will pop up. How do I change the style of this menu? thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can change it through `cardTheme` in `MaterialApp`